# ProgrammingError while Running migrate Command in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-migrations

I have made some changes to my model, changed a CharField to ArrayField. I am using Django 2 and PostgreSQL 11. Now I am getting an error while running migrate command: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type jsonb to character varying[]
LINE 1: ...MN "msg_list" TYPE varchar(500)[] USING "msg_list"::varchar(...

I have googled the topic but I didn't find any solution to the issue.

Here is the code for my model:

```
class Sentence(models.Model):
    sent = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    msg_list = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=500), blank=True, null=True)
    sent_correct = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: It looks like the database If the can’t automatically convert the existing values to an array, so you can do it in several steps. 1. Create a new array field `msg_list2`. 2. Create a data migration to fill your new field with values from the old field. 3. delete the old field. 4. Rename the new field to `msg_list`.

Comment: @Alasdair If I remove null=True, I get a different error message: You are trying to change the nullable field 'msg_list' on sentence to non-nullable without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Ignore for now, and let me handle existing rows with NULL myself (e.g. because you added a RunPython or RunSQL operation to handle NULL values in a previous data migration)
 3) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

Comment: Choose one of the three option it gave you, e.g. quit, add `default=list` to the field, then re-run `makemigrations`.